# Django 3 'NoReverseMatch at /post/1/

Tags: python, django, django-models, jinja2

My blog has the capacity to make posts.  I wanted to have a feature where i can update/edit the blog and when i try to implement the feature i run into the following error;

> NoReverseMatch at /post/1/ Reverse for 'post_edit' with arguments
>   '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['post/(?P[0-9]+)/edit/$']

I know what line is causing the problem:

```
/post_detail.html
<a href="{% url 'post_edit' post.pk %}"> +Edit Blog Post</a>
```

without the line on top, i get no errors. I am just a begginer learning Django and i cannot make any sense of why this is not working.  It is suggested in the tutorial i am following.

/urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('post/<int:pk>/edit/', BlogUpdateView.as_view(), name='post_edit'), # new
    path('post/new/', BlogCreateView.as_view(), name='post_new'),
    path('post/<int:pk>/', BlogDetailView.as_view(), name='post_detail'),
    path('', BlogListView.as_view(), name='home'),
]
```

/post_detail.html

```
 {% extends 'base.html' %}

{%  block content %}
<div class="post-entry">
    <h2>
        {{ my_posts.title }}
    </h2>
    <p>
        {{ my_posts.body }}
    </p>
</div>

<a href="{% url 'post_edit' post.pk %}"> +Edit Blog Post</a>

{% endblock content %}
```

views.py

```
class BlogListView(ListView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'home.html'


class BlogDetailView(DeleteView):
    model = Post
    context_object_name = 'my_posts'
    template_name = 'post_detail.html'

class BlogCreateView(CreateView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'post_new.html'
    fields = '__all__'

class BlogUpdateView(UpdateView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'post_edit.html'
    fields = ['title', 'body']
```

/models.py

```
class Post(models.Model):

    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    author = models.ForeignKey(
        'auth.User',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    )
    body = models.TextField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('post_detail', args=[str(self.id)])
```

Comment: try this   <a href="{%  url 'post_edit'    pk=post.pk %}"> +Edit Blog Post</a>

Comment: `"{% url 'post_edit' my_posts.pk %}"` instead of `"{% url 'post_edit' post.pk %}"`.

Comment: thank you Willem, add your comment as an answer and i i check mark it as correct.  I cant believe i forgot that i reassigned it

Comment: The `context_object_name` is `'my_posts'`, not `'post'`.

Comment: Please don't mention DRF when its not related to it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The name of your context object is: `context_object_name = 'my_posts'`, not `'post'`. Therefore the object is `my_posts` in your template.

The link should thus be:

```
<a href="{% url 'post_edit' my_posts.pk %}"> +Edit Blog Post</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```py
path(r'post/<int:pk>/edit/', BlogUpdateView.as_view(), name='post_edit'), # new
```

I added an `r` in front of your url.

Answer (score 0):

We could write model class name "post" in lowercase or "object" with or without context_object_name to make it work.
<a

```html
<a href="{% url 'post_edit' post.pk %}">+ edit post</a>
or
<a href="{% url 'post_edit' object.pk %}">+ edit post</a>
```

> at post_detail.html